# ansible-inventory --host showing incorrect output

Tags: linux, rhel, ansible

I am not able to fork a successful SSH connection to one of my machines via ansible playbook. Below is the setting that I have configured.

User credential files located under group_vars directory under /etc/ansible/inventory/group_vars/

```
ansible_user: ***
ansible_ssh_pass: ***
ansible_become_pass: ***
```

The whole inventory of the servers is stored in a file under /etc/ansible/inventory/ with below format

```
abc  ansible_host=abc.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The playbook to capture the uptime is as mentioned below

```
---
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - name: collect time
    shell: "uptime"
    register: out
  - debug:
      var: out
...
```

Now the strange thing is this whole scenario worked perfectly till last week and the only change is that server was patched in between. The current version of ansible is 2.10. When I run the command `ansible-inventory --host <hostname>` . It shows me the below output . What is more troubling is that
the details shown for ansible_ssh_pass , ansible_sudo_pass, ansible_user is incorrect. The user is not even created on the server. Can some one please shed some light that where I am going wrong.

```
{
    
    "ansible_become_pass": "*****",
    "ansible_host": "emdc1sql03.emea.media.global.loc",
    "ansible_ssh_pass": "test123",
    "ansible_sudo_pass": "test123",
    "ansible_user": "test1"
}
```

Comment: I have seen a very similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/624679/216907) 12 hours ago. Is it somehow related to this issue?

Comment: What is the `group_vars/` file called? Is the server in a corresponding group?